# Read CSV containing Strings & int to arraylist with try/catch

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, import, try-catch

I'm hoping some might be able to suggest an alternate method to a program I'm working on. I've done the below *test* code to display my query without having to post my full code.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    ArrayList<Students> chemistry = new ArrayList<>();

    public void loadClass() {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Chemistry.csv"))) {
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                try {
                    chemistry.add(new Students(values[0], values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2]),
                            Integer.parseInt(values[3]), Integer.parseInt(values[4])));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("You have some text in a number field for entry: " + values[0] + " " + values[1]);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The file has not been found in the path \"" + (new File(".").getAbsoluteFile()) + "\"");
            System.out.println("Please place the CSV file at this location");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry an input/output error has occured.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("students loaded from the file are:");

        for (Students pupils : chemistry) {
            System.out.println("Student " + pupils.getFirstName() + " " + pupils.getSurname() + " was born in "
                    + pupils.getBirthYear() + "/" + pupils.getBirthMonth() + " /"
                    + pupils.getBirthDay());
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe number of students in the class is: " + chemistry.size());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.loadClass();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Students {
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private int birthYear;
    private int birthMonth;
    private int birthDay;

    // All-args constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Here is the CSV data I'm using in the *Chemistry.csv* file

```
First Name,Surname,Year of Birth,Month of Birth,Day of Birth
Joe,Bloggs,2002,12,8
Jane,Bloggs,2003,11,15
Harry,Smith,2004,10,2
William,Wallace,2001,9,7
Philip,Jones,2002,Aug,9th
```

As you can see in my CSV file, I've deliberately put a string entry for the month and day in the last line. This is to test my NumberFormatException try/catch.

It works and the user gets prompted that there's an error with that line entry, but this is a small dataset. I'm wondering what I can do when there may be hundreds of lines.

I was thinking that in the catch I could have something that would replace the invalid String with a valid int number.  I know in this case I would have to engineer an if/else or switch statement to account for the 12 months and 30(ish) days, however I would just like '0' to be entered for now.

I'm not sure how to pass *int 0* as a default value for this as my *chemistry.add* line parses the file.

I also thought there may be an alternate way of entering the values into my ArrayList so I can put the try/catch around just the *Integer.parseInt* bits, but again, I'm not sure of another method.

Can anyone suggest a good option to investigate?

EDIT:
After the comment by g00se below, I used this instead and it seemed to work:

```java
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int third, fourth, fifth;
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                String first = values[0];
                String second = values[1];
                try {
                    third = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e3) {
                    third = 0;
                }
                try {
                    fourth = Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e4) {
                    fourth = 0;
                }
                try {
                    fifth = Integer.parseInt(values[4]);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e5) {
                    fifth = 0;
                }
                    chemistry.add(new Student(first, second, third, fourth, fifth));
            }
```

Needs some tidying up but at least I have a way forward...

Comment: Your code is generally good (though your class should be called ```Student``` ) and if you separate each ```parseInt``` into separate try-catch blocks, you can catch the exception and substitute the default value before calling the ctor of ```Student```

Comment: So I need to read the line in the CSV, parse the individual values on each line, with try/catch using int = 0 for the int variables and after that's done, pass them through to the chemistry.add?
would I need to store each value as a temp local variable, then use that temp local variable in the add statement, and the while loop would take care of moving down the lines?

Comment: Basically, yes. Your split pattern should be ```"\\s*,\\s*"``` . I'll let you work out why

Comment: Ah, you should delete that (unreadable) comment and join it with your posted code. I would do the initializations first and have the catch block empty, *apart* from a comment as to *why* it's empty